# Abrir galería de imágenes en Android

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para descargar imágenes, las cuales guardo en la tarjeta SD.
El tema es que quiero acceder a la carpeta que las contiene, que se llama "Pictures" para que puedan ser compartidas, por ejemplo (como la galería de imágenes).

El problema es que accedo a la carpeta bien, pero al hacer clic en alguna de las imágenes descargadas, se cierra la vista y me retorna a mi aplicación.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       // Toast.makeText(this,"opciones funcionando ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.navigate){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }

    if(id ==  R.id.opengallery) {
        Log.v("LOAD","GALLERy");
        openFolder();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void openFolder()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath() + "/Pictures/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Comment: Has visto que error muestra en el LogCat? probablemente se debe a permisos.

Comment: Intenta agregando a tu Manifest los permisos, por lo regular ese es el problema. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />